# Demo variable in the child component ngOnChanges is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

In the child.component.ts although. I am using demo variable with input(). it not showing in the developer console

app.html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="text" #val>
<br>
<button (click)="submitValue(val)">submit</button>
<app-child [myValue]="value"></app-child>
```

app.componet.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'cat';


  value : string;
  submitValue(val){

    this.value=val.value;

    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

child.html

```
<p>from child...!</p>
<strong>{{myValue}}</strong>
```

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {

  constructor() { 

    console.log('constructor called');

  }

  @Input() myValue='ux trend';
  @Input() demo='';

  ngOnInit() {
  console.log('onInit called');

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChanges){

    console.log(changes);
  }

}
```

In the Chrome developer console, I see this:

```
{myValue: SimpleChange}
myValue: SimpleChange {previousValue: undefined, currentValue: undefined, firstChange: true}
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toString: ƒ ()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Demo variable with input(). it not showing in the developer console.

Only showing myValue

Answer (score 1):

> Demo variable with input(). it not showing in the developer console.

Yes, because you are not passing it for the `ChildComponent`.

Your current code:

```
<app-child [myValue]="value"></app-child>
```

So to detect it,

```
<app-child [myValue]="value" [demo]="someAmazingText"></app-child>
```

---

If you want to check if the `myValue` variable changed or want to access current value then you have to use:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange }) {
  if(changes['myValue'] && changes['myValue'].previousValue != changes['myValue'].currentValue)
  {
    console.log('The latest value', changes['myValue'].currentValue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected. Initially you are sending `value` variable without assigning it any value. So it is sending `undefined`. Notice `myValue: SimpleChange {previousValue: undefined, currentValue: undefined, firstChange: true}`. Both `previousValue` and `currentValue` are `undefined` because you sent undefined.

To see changes, type a value into the input box and hit Submit. Now the new value should be available in `changes['myValue'].currentValue` in your child component.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8rxoaq) is the stackblitz for your code. I haven't changed anything.

[image: Screenshot from stackblitz]